# Difficult with LineChart

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I  need help about LineChart:

Situation:

I have a LineChart with some data acquired by Oracle query, I have in select the columns ValorC, ValorP, Sla and OBS, where OBS="Justification if some problem occurred in ValorC". The problem is How can I show this value when put mouse over the point (value) in chart ? I can work with DataTip?

```
<mx:series>             
  <mx:LineSeries id="IDValor"  displayName="Execução Diária" yField="ValorC" showDataEffect="seriesInterpolate" />
  <mx:LineSeries id="IDValorP" displayName="Meta Produção" yField="ValorP" showDataEffect="seriesInterpolate" />
  <mx:LineSeries id="IDSLA"    displayName="Sla Acordado" yField="Sla"  showDataEffect="seriesInterpolate"/>
</mx:series>
```

Comment: Yes you should be able to achieve this using data tips, can you explain what you've tried and what has gone wrong? http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_displayingdata_08.html

Comment: Tks shaunhusain, I searched in livedocs and google but I didn't find how a get a column OBS and agregation it on a ValorC dataTip.Tks for help

Comment: Guys, I resolved the problem with two funcions:
- 1º  `public function init():void {
        chart.addEventListener(ChartItemEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER, minhaSolicitacao);`
- 2 º `     public function minhaSolicitacao(e:ChartItemEvent):void {
        TextObs.text = e.hitData.item.OBS;
     }`
*OBS are visible=false
TKS for ALL
     }`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with two funcions: 
- 1º 
`public function init():void { chart.addEventListener(ChartItemEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER, minhaSolicitacao); }`
- 2 º 
`public function minhaSolicitacao(e:ChartItemEvent):void { TextObs.text = e.hitData.item.OBS; }`
*OBS are visible=false TKS for ALL